# In SQLite are subqueries as fast as using fixed values?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I am using a view to retrieve and display products, at the moment this list only has a couple of hundred entries, but it could potentially go up to millions.

I also have a table which contains a list of products.

Which would be faster to execute? the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Products_view where code IN (SELECT code from Products Where [clause])
```

or first retrieving the data in the subquery:

```
SELECT code from Products Where [clause]
```

and then executing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products_view where code IN (val1,val2,val3....)
```

as a side note, yes I know that I could join the two tables and then execute the where on the join, but in this case it will not work.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to test the above, took me a couple of hours :) but here are the results:

I managed to fill the product_view with 271,226,592 items and the subquery table (products) with 13,272 items.

I measured the time it took to read each, with sqlitestudio.
Here are the results:

When retrieving items from the subquery table 
Using IN :

```
select * from product_view where code in (
select code from products limit y,x)
```

Using FIXED:

```
Select code from products limit y,x; 
select * from product_view where code in ('values'....)
```

where y is a random number and x is the number in each of the below headers

### 10 rows from products retrieves 194142 rows from view

```
       1st try   2nd try   3rd try   4th try   5th try   |  Average    |  Total
IN     0.006458  0.006182  0.005339  0.005902  0.005523  |  0.0058808  |  0.0058808
FIXED  0.000277  0.000295  0.000217  0.000215  0.000303  |  0.0002614  |
    +  0.005887  0.006221  0.004748  0.004511  0.005724  |  0.0054182  |  0.0056796
```

### 20 rows from products retrieves 367848 rows from view

```
       1st try   2nd try   3rd try   4th try   5th try   |  Average    |  Total
IN     0.004724  0.004552  0.007573  0.005836  0.005913  |  0.0057196  |  0.0057196
FIXED  0.000260  0.000430  0.000267  0.000509  0.000646  |  0.0004224  |
    +  0.004682  0.006082  0.006079  0.004760  0.006242  |  0.0055690  |  0.0059914
```

### 50 rows from products retrieves 848094 rows from view

```
       1st try   2nd try   3rd try   4th try   5th try   |  Average    |  Total
IN     0.004729  0.004773  0.004701  0.004916  0.006257  |  0.0050752  |  0.0050752
FIXED  0.000463  0.000383  0.000418  0.000348  0.000342  |  0.0003908  |
    +  0.005873  0.004759  0.005034  0.004911  0.004796  |  0.0050746  |  0.0054654
```

### 100 rows from products retrieves 1496937 rows from view

```
       1st try   2nd try   3rd try   4th try   5th try   |  Average    |  Total
IN     0.004861  0.004720  0.004819  0.004874  0.005934  |  0.0050416  |  0.0050416
FIXED  0.001217  0.000361  0.000327  0.000337  0.000338  |  0.0005160  |
    +  0.004855  0.005020  0.004896  0.005891  0.004994  |  0.0051312  |  0.0056472
```

so in effect it seems that the differences are not that big, no more than +- 0.0005 seconds